# Image File Execution Options, legit or malicious use?

Tags: debugging, executable, execution, malware

I am trying to understand what Image File Executions Options can do and what it's normally used for. I know it is used for debugging purposes but how do I know its used for malicious purposes? Is this registry key used with every executable? If not, is it suspicious?

For example what does \Image File Execution Options\DevOverrideEnable do?

PS: I have looked a these sources already:

https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17352/Image-File-Execution-Options-Good-Evil-Fun/28441

https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options/

Answer (score 0):

Normally debuggers can run a process or attach to existing process to debug it and it's enough for normal projects but in some projects like services debugger can't start the service because of Windows service architecture. in this scenario we should attach debugger to running service process but if we want to debug some codes in startup of service we can't do it by this method because debugger attached to process after the startup codes executed.

In scenarios like this we can use Image File Executions Options (IFEO) by configuring to launch debugger when process start, when specified process start Windows launch process inside specified debugger and let developer to debug the process from beginning of born !

The problem of this option is Microsoft Windows do not (and cannot ;) check the specified debugger is really a debugge.

On the other hand malware authors use this option as a trick to start they malicious process when some process run, for example they can run a injector every time "explorer.exe" process run and inject some malicious code to it.

Finally IFEO is not malicious option by it self but maybe! and there is not simple way to know it's malicious or not. if you want to be sure it's malicious or not the debugger should be analyze and check manually for malicious activity.

If you are not computer skilled person the easiest way for you is to find the IFEO registry keys and find debugger's path from theme and upload debugger file to online scanner website like VirusTotal and hope they tell the truth :))